Why use "at" instead of "because?"
everyone!
I came across a sentence that stated:
"Excitement for this opportunity, mixed with sadness at leaving behind my family and friends."
How is it "at" and not "because" or "due to?"
Isn't "at" used for places? Please enlighten me, thank you.

At is used for both places and times (at night, at the moment) as well as to indicate cause, as Michael says.

Note that one of the more literal senses of at (and by) is in proximity. That sense is metaphorically extended in things like I'm surprised at / by the news, He jumped at the sound, where you can infer that some reaction is caused by the [sudden] proximity of some new stimulus.

The OP writes:

Isn't "at" used for places? Please enlighten me, thank you.

What does it mean to be "at the door" or "at the edge of the cliff" or "at an impasse"?  Those circumstances are more or less tangible, right there in front of you.  They are there. A doorway.  A cliff-edge. A blockage. Physical places or situations.
at can be used with situations that are "there" before you existentially or psychologically, if not there physically.
You can laugh at something.
You can balk at something requested or expected of you, that is, express with some degree of  resentment that you do not wish to do it. It causes that feeling in you.
You can feel sadness at having to say goodbye.
Those are emotional situations, which are like "psychological places" rather than physical places.
So this usage of at is not as arbitrary and different as it may seem at first.

One of the uses of the preposition 'at' is to talk about the cause of something, especially feelings, such as excitement and sadness.

at preposition (CAUSE) A2
used to show the cause of something,especially a feeling:
We were surprised at the news.
I was quite excited at the prospect.
Why does no one ever laugh at my jokes?

At (preposition) Cambridge Dictionary

Ok, you got this one.
